# nativeQuery agument with PageRequest

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to pass a companyid to a native query in my respository that uses the PageRequest but my query does not pick up the argument.

Perhaps I cannot use PageRequest and need to use Pageable instead(Too green to know). I have looked around but I cant find what I am doing wrong.

This is my code in the Repository:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE deleted = '0' AND companyid = ?1",nativeQuery = true)
Page<User> findAllNotDeleted(PageRequest pageRequest, Long companyid);
```

but this is the result I get :

Hibernate: `SELECT * FROM user WHERE deleted = '0' AND companyid = ? order by id desc limit ?`

I am a bit lost here. Any help would be very very welcome.

Thanks

Robby

Answer (score 0):

For custom queries, it doesn't recognize it by default so you need to mention the countQuery :

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE companyid = ?1",
countQuery = "select count(*) from user where companyid = ?1, 
nativeQuery = true)
Page<User> findAllNotDeleted(Long companyid,PageRequest pageRequest);
```

Comment: Thanks Man 
I tried that also as I thought the same thing but I get

Ordinal parameter not bound : 2; nested exception is org.hibernate.QueryException: Ordinal parameter not bound : 2

Comment: Try changing it like this `@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE deleted = '0' AND companyid = ?1",nativeQuery = true)
Page<User> findAllNotDeleted(Long companyid,PageRequest pageRequest);` 
otherwise, change PageRequest to Pageable

Comment: Try also using named parameter  `@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE deleted = '0' AND companyid = :companyId",nativeQuery = true)
Page<User> findAllNotDeleted(@Param("companyId") Long companyId,PageRequest pageRequest);` and tell me about your hibernate log

Comment: Dammit .. Still didnt work .. I now get
findAllNotDeleted(java.lang.Long,org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest) but parameter 'Optional[pageRequest]' not found in annotated query 'SELECT * FROM user WHERE deleted = '0' AND companyid = :companyId

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I have just edited the answer, you can try it if you still have the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out PageRequest is a crappy option to use. I did the same code with Pageable and now it works. Still not sure why PageRequest limits other arguments getting in the Query